# Ошибка opencv python "label() got an unexpected keyword argument 'neighbors'" 'это стандратная строка, библиотека тоже работает почему у меня ошибка?

Tags: python, opencv

Работаю над кодом с использованием Open CV. Не понимаю почему у меня ошибка в стандартной строке `labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0`),
а именно

> "Exception has occurred: TypeError label() got an unexpected keyword argument 'neighbors'"

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils import contours
import skimage
from skimage import measure
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image file")
ap.add_argument("-r", "--radius", type = int,
    help = "radius of Gaussian blur; must be odd")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the image and convert it to grayscale
#image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
image = cv2.imread("2.jpg")

#image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=4)
#print(image)

labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0)
mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
# loop over the unique components
for label in np.unique(labels):
    #if this is the background label, ignore it
    if label == 0:
        continue
    # otherwise, construct the label mask and count the
    # number of pixels 
    labelMask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
    labelMask[labels == label] = 255
    numPixels = cv2.countNonZero(labelMask)
    # if the number of pixels in the component is sufficiently
    # large, then add it to our mask of "large blobs"
    if numPixels > 300:
        mask = cv2.add(mask, labelMask)
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что-то я не вижу параметра `neighbors` у [skimage.measure.label](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходим в [документацию](http://devdoc.net/python/scikit-image-doc-0.13.1/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) и видим, что `neighbors` устарел и нужно использовать `connectivity`.